# Assigning rank in another sheet based on Average

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have a list of names with an average beside it for every day Monday-Friday. A subgroup of names within this list will be highlighted. I want a macro to assign ranks of the highlighted individuals based on their average and place a value of their rank in a row of another sheet where each individual has a column. There is one row for each day.

Example. 5 people highlighted in a list of July 1st. Macro looks at other sheet (called Workbook) and finds row corresponding to July 1st. Then finds column corresponding to person with lowest average. Puts 1 in their cell. Repeats this with 2, 3, 4, 5.  If 8 people highlighted would do this 1 through 8.

Link to a copy of the sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DZif3MWw4xnyrK54OSm-htIty4G9XwMNZstROzaFk94/edit?usp=sharing

hope this makes sense

Comment: pls share a copy of your sheet

Comment: added link. thank you.

Comment: This question doesn't look like a practical, detailed question about using Google Sheets. On the other hand, while a link to an external resource might be helpful, posts should be self-contained.

Comment: Your point is fair but this thread has been dead for 4 years...

Answer (score 0):

- paste in **P8** cell, then select **P8** press <kbd>**`CTRL`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`C`**</kbd> and paste in **S8**, **V8**, **Y8**, etc.

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SORT(TRANSPOSE({'Workbook '!$E2:$P2; RANK(INDIRECT("Workbook !"&
   ADDRESS(MATCH(P5, 'Workbook '!$D:$D, 0), 5, 4)&":"&
   ADDRESS(MATCH(P5, 'Workbook '!$D:$D, 0), 16, 4))*1, INDIRECT("Workbook !"&
   ADDRESS(MATCH(P5, 'Workbook '!$D:$D, 0), 5, 4)&":"&
   ADDRESS(MATCH(P5, 'Workbook '!$D:$D, 0), 16, 4))*1)}), 2, 1)))
  ```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate this reply. Can you walk me though how this works? I'm struggling to follow the logic. Thanks.

Comment: @LanceSalmikivi sure, with MATCH we get number of row where P5 is equal to row from D:D range. this number is then inserted into ADDRESS formula so we get range E4 then with INDIRECT we create a range E4:P4. this is then inserted into RANK formula which assigns a rank to each number in range E4:P4 (if E4:P4 is empty you will get value error so to counter that we multyply it wit 1 so if the range is empty after multiplication its 0) then this ranked row is combined with names E2:P2 in array brackets {}. next the TRANSPOSE turns rows into columns and SORT sorts both columns based on 2nd column